# Messages in SpringIntegration

Tags: spring-integration

I have QueueChannel with the message-store attribute. Its configuration

```
<int:channel id="channel1">
    <int:queue message-store="msgStore"></int:queue
</int:channel>
```

Then I want to send messages from channel "channel1" using `<int-http:outbound-gateway/>`

It looks so:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="someUrl"
        http-method="PUT"
        request-channel="channel1">
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3">
            <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="2.0" maximum="8000"/>
        </int:retry-advice>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

My problem:
    If the message couldn't be sent, I need that it be in the channel "channel1". But it always is removed from channel.
    How do that it remains in the channel?

**EDIT1.**

```
<int:poller
    default="true"
    fixed-rate="100"
    receive-timeout="100">
 <int:transactional/>
 </int:poller>
```

**EDIT2**

```
 <int-jdbc:message-store
    id="msgStore" data-source="jdbcSQLiteDataSource"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration doesn't look right - you need a poller on the gateway to poll the channel for messages.

Without a transaction, you can't "leave it in the channel" after a failure; you could put it back into the channel with an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (and a flow on its failure channel to transform the error message back to the original), but it will be at the tail of the queue, not the head.

If you message store supports transactions, you can make the poller transactional and the failure will rollback the message into the store.

Comment: You also can use `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` to process `ErrorMessage` with the re-sending `failedMessage` to the queue back. But, eh, that is a tail now not the head, as Gary says.

Comment: @ArtemBilan
1.  I have configuration for <Poller>,  See my edited post
2. I need to return message so that it will be at the  head queue.

Comment: That is Gary's answer. I just try to provide more useful info. Yes, I assumed that you have a `default` `<poller>`. Now consider one of suggested solution for your use-case.

Comment: I be able to return message in the head of the queue only with the poller transactional?

Comment: I don't understand how I have to add a poller transactional. I did so as in my edited post. But messages  are removed still from the channel.

Comment: What message store are you using? Does it support transactions?

Comment: We use SQLite mesasge store

Comment: Please, see Edit2 in my post

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and look at the logs regarding transactions.

Comment: Got it, I'll look. One moment, do I have to set poller(transactional) for outbound-gateway or for other component?